# Theme doesn't work on dojo's website?

Tags: javascript, css, dojo

http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/themePreviewer/demo.html
In this theme previewer, no matter how I change theme, nothing happens.
Besides, in any samples of the reference guide, when I try to run them, they appear without styles at all, as if the css is not present.
I tried other browsers, all the same.
Although it works well on my project, I wonder what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine that it would ever work. I looked at the source code and it doesn't look like it's even attempting to change the CSS location or the classname on the body (both are required to change the theme).

The only thing that seems to happen is that the `?theme=` query parameter is only used to define which themes should be displayed as link. But even that's going wrong. They define the themes like this:

```
var availableThemes = [
  { theme: "claro", author: "Dojo", baseUri: "../themes/" },
  { theme: "tundra", author: "Dojo", baseUri: "../themes/" },
  { theme: "soria", author: "nikolai", baseUri: "../themes/" },
  { theme: "nihilo", author: "nikolai", baseUri: "../themes/" }
];
```

Then they load the current theme like this:

```
var curTheme = location.search.replace(/.*theme=([a-z]+).*/, "$1") || "claro";
```

And then they attempt to load the correct menu options:

```
var tmpString = '';
array.forEach(availableThemes, function(theme){
  if(theme != curTheme){
    tmpString +=
      '<a href="?theme=' + theme.theme + '">' + theme.theme + '</' + 'a> (' +
      '<a href="?theme=' + theme.theme + '&dir=rtl">RTL</' + 'a> ' +
      '<a href="?theme=' + theme.theme + '&a11y=true">high-contrast</' + 'a> ' +
      '<a href="?theme=' + theme.theme + '&dir=rtl&a11y=true">RTL+high-contrast</' + 'a> )' +
      ' - by: ' + theme.author + ' <br>';
  }
});
```

But as you can see they're comparing objects to strings (`theme != curTheme`), which will never work. So, the code seems to be quite errorneous, so I think you can't rely on it. I suggest opening a ticket to report this issue.

---

If you're interested in how things look like in the other theme, you can open your DevTools and change the CSS file (`../../dijit/themes/claro/claro.css` should be replaced) and you should change the classname on the `<body>` tag.

Or you could simply execute the following code in your browser's console:

```
(function() {
    var curTheme = location.search.replace(/.*theme=([a-z]+).*/, "$1") || "claro",
        newStyle = document.createElement("link"),
        styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
    newStyle.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    newStyle.setAttribute("type", "text/css");


    for (var idx = 0; idx < styleSheets.length; idx++) {
        if (styleSheets[idx].href.indexOf("claro.css") >= 0) {
            newStyle.setAttribute("href", styleSheets[idx].href.replace(/claro/g, curTheme));
        }
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newStyle);
    document.body.className = curTheme;
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Dijit theme tester](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.10.2/dojo-release-1.10.2/dijit/themes/themeTester.html) instead, which lives in the Dijit package under the themes folder.

You'll probably think it looks nearly identical.  It sort of is - the themePreviewer under the demos folder was sort of half-copied from it at some point, but has unfortunately never fully worked, AFAIK.

Comment: Indeed, I opened a ticket for it and Bill said the same thing.